# CancelAnimationFrame is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

My intention of creating this code snippet is to move images to the left as much as I scroll. However, the more I scroll, the faster it moves to the left, and it doesn't stop. console.log(raf); I wrote down the code. The number keeps increasing and not decreasing. CancelAnimationFrame (raf); Code does not appear to be functioning properly. What's the reason?

```js
"use strict";

const FRICTION = 0.9;
const VELOCITY = 0.08;

const MODE_CSS = 'css';
const MODE_JS = 'js';
const MODE_SCROLL = 'scroll';

const DIRECTION_LEFT = -1;
const DIRECTION_RIGHT = 1;
const DIRECTION_BOTH = 0;

const textTicker = document.querySelector(".text-ticker");
const texts = document.querySelectorAll(".text-ticker__text");

const mobile =
  /Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
  (navigator.platform === "MacIntel" && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1);

const lerp = (s, e, m) => s * (1 - m) + e * m;

let mode = getMode();
let direction = getDirection();
let velocity = {
  target: VELOCITY * direction,
  current: VELOCITY * direction
};
let progress = 0;
let raf = null;
let inView = true;
let isAnimating = false;

function onRaf() {
  // do nothing if we have no text to move
  if (!texts) return;

  if (!isAnimating) {
    isAnimating = true;
    raf = requestAnimationFrame(onRaf);

    // apply friction
    velocity.target *= FRICTION;

    // set minimal velocity based on is current direction (only for JS mode)
    if (mode === MODE_JS) {
      if (velocity.target > 0) velocity.target = Math.max(VELOCITY, velocity.target);
      else velocity.target = Math.min(VELOCITY * -1, velocity.target);
    }

    // lerp velocity
    velocity.current = lerp(velocity.current, velocity.target, 0.2);

    // update progression
    progress += velocity.current;

    // limits to [-100, 0]
    if (progress < -100) progress = progress + 100;
    else if (progress > 0) progress = progress - 100;

    // apply transformations if inView
    if (inView) texts.forEach(text => (text.style.transform = `translate3d(${progress}%, 0, 0)`));

    isAnimating = false;
  }
}

function getDirection() {
  if (textTicker.classList.contains('--direction-left')) return DIRECTION_LEFT;
  else if (textTicker.classList.contains('--direction-both')) return DIRECTION_BOTH;
  else if (textTicker.classList.contains('--direction-right')) return DIRECTION_RIGHT;
}

function getMode() {
  if (mobile) return MODE_CSS;

  switch (textTicker.dataset.textTicker) {
    case MODE_CSS:
      return MODE_CSS;
    case MODE_SCROLL:
      return MODE_SCROLL;
    default:
      return MODE_JS;
  }
}

let timer = null;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (timer !== null) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    raf = requestAnimationFrame(onRaf);
  }
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    if (raf) {
      console.log(raf); // The number keeps getting bigger.
      cancelAnimationFrame(raf); // This code is not working.
    }
  }, 150);
}, false);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.spacer {
  height: 80vh;
}

@keyframes tickerText {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.text-ticker {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 1%;
}

.text-ticker__text>img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #00f;
}

.text-ticker.--mode-css .text-ticker__text {
  animation-name: tickerText;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.text-ticker.--mode-css .text-ticker__text {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.text-ticker.--mode-css.is-inview .text-ticker__text {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.text-ticker.--mode-js .text-ticker__text {
  animation: none;
  will-change: transform;
}

.text-ticker.--mode-css.--direction-right .text-ticker__text {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Change the X value quickly when scrolling</title>
  <link href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="./js/script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="text-ticker is-inview --mode-js --direction-left" data-text-ticker="js">
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7288141" alt="image 01">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7790227" alt="image 02">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7786568" alt="image 03">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-5202140" alt="image 04">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7288141" alt="image 05">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7790227" alt="image 06">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7786568" alt="image 07">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-5202140" alt="image 08">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First, it's a bit surprising to edit a previous question to ask another one entirely. I don't think this is good etiquette and you might be better asking a new question entirely.

Comment: Writing blocked in stack overflow. So I can't ask you a new question. So I wrote a new post again in the previously deleted post. I hope the closed post is reopened so that I can write again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll event will fire at quite an high frequency (actually at the screen refresh rate, like `requestAnimationFrame` [*hereafter `rAF`*]).
So by the time your timeout handler fires (250+ms after it's been scheduled), a few of these events might have fired (~9 on a 60Hz monintor, ~18 on 120Hz one). All these events will clear the previous timer that was supposed to cancel the scheduled `rAF`. So every time a new scroll event occurs, a new `rAF` loop starts and only the last one gets canceled ~150ms after it started. All the ones started in between keep running.

What you want is a flag letting you know if you're already animating. If it's set, you don't start a new `rAF` loop.
You already had an `isAnimating` flag, but that flag was mostly useless: you raise it at the beginning of the `rAF` callback, and lower it at the end of that same callback, **synchronously**. You want this flag to be raised for as long as the animation is on. The easiest is probably to handle it outside of your `rAF` loop.

```js
"use strict";

const FRICTION = 0.9;
const VELOCITY = 0.08;

const MODE_CSS = 'css';
const MODE_JS = 'js';
const MODE_SCROLL = 'scroll';

const DIRECTION_LEFT = -1;
const DIRECTION_RIGHT = 1;
const DIRECTION_BOTH = 0;

const textTicker = document.querySelector(".text-ticker");
const texts = document.querySelectorAll(".text-ticker__text");

const mobile =
  /Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
  (navigator.platform === "MacIntel" && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1);

const lerp = (s, e, m) => s * (1 - m) + e * m;

let mode = getMode();
let direction = getDirection();
let velocity = {
  target: VELOCITY * direction,
  current: VELOCITY * direction
};
let progress = 0;
let raf = null;
let inView = true;
let isAnimating = false;

function onRaf() {
  // do nothing if we have no text to move or if we've been told the animation is over
  if (!texts || !isAnimating) return;

  // apply friction
  velocity.target *= FRICTION;

  // set minimal velocity based on is current direction (only for JS mode)
  if (mode === MODE_JS) {
    if (velocity.target > 0) velocity.target = Math.max(VELOCITY, velocity.target);
    else velocity.target = Math.min(VELOCITY * -1, velocity.target);
  }

  // lerp velocity
  velocity.current = lerp(velocity.current, velocity.target, 0.2);

  // update progression
  progress += velocity.current;

  // limits to [-100, 0]
  if (progress < -100) progress = progress + 100;
  else if (progress > 0) progress = progress - 100;

  // apply transformations if inView
  if (inView) texts.forEach(text => (text.style.transform = `translate3d(${progress}%, 0, 0)`));

  raf = requestAnimationFrame(onRaf);
}

function getDirection() {
  if (textTicker.classList.contains('--direction-left')) return DIRECTION_LEFT;
  else if (textTicker.classList.contains('--direction-both')) return DIRECTION_BOTH;
  else if (textTicker.classList.contains('--direction-right')) return DIRECTION_RIGHT;
}

function getMode() {
  if (mobile) return MODE_CSS;

  switch (textTicker.dataset.textTicker) {
    case MODE_CSS:
      return MODE_CSS;
    case MODE_SCROLL:
      return MODE_SCROLL;
    default:
      return MODE_JS;
  }
}

let timer = null;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {  
  if (!isAnimating) {
    isAnimating = true;
    onRaf(); // We're basically already in an animation frame
             // Calling rAF here is almost the same as scheduling a microtask
             // i.e, quite useless.
  }
  // Wait 150ms from now to stop the animation
  // next time we'll come here this will just move
  // the time we stop the animation a bit further
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => isAnimating = false, 150);
  
}, false);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.spacer {
  height: 80vh;
}

@keyframes tickerText {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.text-ticker {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 1%;
}

.text-ticker__text>img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #00f;
}

.text-ticker.--mode-css .text-ticker__text {
  animation-name: tickerText;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.text-ticker.--mode-css .text-ticker__text {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.text-ticker.--mode-css.is-inview .text-ticker__text {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.text-ticker.--mode-js .text-ticker__text {
  animation: none;
  will-change: transform;
}

.text-ticker.--mode-css.--direction-right .text-ticker__text {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Change the X value quickly when scrolling</title>
  <link href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="./js/script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="text-ticker is-inview --mode-js --direction-left" data-text-ticker="js">
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7288141" alt="image 01">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7790227" alt="image 02">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7786568" alt="image 03">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-5202140" alt="image 04">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7288141" alt="image 05">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7790227" alt="image 06">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-7786568" alt="image 07">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ticker__text">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/images/id-5202140" alt="image 08">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```